# Extracting numbers from python vars

Tags: python, regex

Basically I am **scraping** a website and saving the results in a var. Let's say i have this in my code:

```
worldPopulation = [scraping and such]
```

Now "worldPopulation" variable has this content:

```
545.452.432.675
```

Worlds Total Population

Note: there's a whitespace line above and under the var. So 2 lines full of blank.

I've been trying to extract the numbers and parse them to a SQLite3 database. I'm using INT as datatype, and I've tried this:

```
 re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', worldPopulation)
```

and also

```
re.findall(r'\d+', worldPopulation)
```

both gave me errors, which are:

```
Line 241, in find all
return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Does anyone know how can I retrieve that number from the variable? Its in milions so I don't really want to split the number in 4 sets of 3 numbers, just wanted it as a whole.

Comment: Variables contain strings.  Same thing.  What errors do you get?  Be precise.  The first example expects spaces on both sides of the number, which you don't have.  The second one should have grabbed the four numbers separately.

Comment: What error are you getting? The regexp looks fine.

Comment: Please provide a more complete example. You say "both gave me errors", but depending on how `worldPopulation` is defined, that doesn't need to be the case (although the numbers won't include the periods). Please provide a definition of `worldPopulation` that matches the actual type of its contents

Comment: I suspect the problem is that `worldPopulation` doesn't actually contain a string. Add your code that creates that variable.

Comment: FYI it’s __scraping__ (and __scrape__, __scraper__, __scraped__) not scrapping

Answer (score 0):

The following should help you:

```py
import re

worldPopulation = '545.452.432.675 Worlds Total Population'

worldPopulation_number = int(re.sub('[a-zA-Z. ]','',worldPopulation))
```

If what you look for are the numbers separated. This might help you:

```py
import re

worldPopulation = '545.452.432.675 Worlds Total Population'

worldPopulation_numbers = [int(x) for x in re.sub('[a-zA-Z ]','',worldPopulation).split('.')]
```

Comment: This will merge all the numbers into a single number, probably not what is wanted.

Comment: E.g. `3 dogs and 10 cats` would produce `310`.

Comment: I just made an edit, If that does not help, then I could not understand what the author is looking for.

Comment: Already tried It, same error: expected string or bytes-like object